# C# Interop Word - Read RTF data from a string

Tags: c#, ms-word, load, interop, word-2003

I have RTF data in a string `str` and i would like that data to be loaded in MS word object. I've seen `Documents.Open()`method but it needs a physical file path to read a particular file and i don't have such file.

How do i open new instance of Word and load my RTF data in it ?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordapp = new ApplicationClass();
wordapp.Visible = false;

string str = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0\fprq2 Arial;}{\f1\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2 Arial;}{\f2\froman\fcharset2\fprq2 Symbol;}}
{\colortbl;}{\stylesheet{\s0\itap0\nowidctlpar\f0\fs24 [Normal];}{\*\cs10\additive Default Paragraph Font;}}{\*\generator TX_RTF32 17.0.540.502;}
\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1138\margt1138\margr1138\margb1138\deftab1134\widowctrl\formshade\sectd\headery720\footery720\pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn1138\margtsxn1138\margrsxn1138\margbsxn1138\pgbrdropt32\pard\itap0\nowidctlpar\plain\f1\fs20 test1\par }";
```

I will be doing some formatting in word but the applicationClass should be `wordapp.Visible = false;`

**UPDATE:** I wouldn't prefer the file to be saved on system. isn't there anyway to read and work without saving it on physical memory ?

Comment: If i got your point correctly , you want to do formating of Rtf data without physical file. You may check RichTextBox control for this

Comment: @faheemkhan: Well that's a good start. I could read the str in richtextbox.Now i am gonna try loading it in a new instance of word doc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to load the RTF text into Word, I think it's better to load it into a text file (since RTF files are plain text anyway), then open that raw RTF text file as a new Word document. This causes Word to process the RTF text and format it as a Word doc (with the fonts/margins/etc), which I think is what you're looking for, not to see the RTF text verbatim. Once it's a new Word doc, you can do your manipulations and then save to a Word doc file:

```
        string filePath = @"c:\rawRtfText.rtf";

        //write the raw RTF string to a text file.
        System.IO.StreamWriter rawTextFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, false);
        string str = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0\fprq2 Arial;}{\f1\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2 Arial;}{\f2\froman\fcharset2\fprq2 Symbol;}}{\colortbl;}{\stylesheet{\s0\itap0\nowidctlpar\f0\fs24 [Normal];}{\*\cs10\additive Default Paragraph Font;}}{\*\generator TX_RTF32 17.0.540.502;}\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1138\margt1138\margr1138\margb1138\deftab1134\widowctrl\formshade\sectd\headery720\footery720\pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn1138\margtsxn1138\margrsxn1138\margbsxn1138\pgbrdropt32\pard\itap0\nowidctlpar\plain\f1\fs20 test1\par }";
        rawTextFile.Write(str);
        rawTextFile.Close();

        //now open the RTF file using word.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application msWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        msWord.Visible = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = msWord.Documents.Open(filePath);

        //after manipulating the word doc, save it as a word doc.
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        wordDoc.SaveAs(@"c:\RtfConvertedToWord.doc", ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Comment: Is your goal to do something like print it, or show it to the user, and then close it without saving? Or to manipulate the formatting of the RTF in an easier fashion and then ultimately retrieve the RTF data that represents that formatting? That is to say, to do things like set fonts/formatting/etc using a Word as an interface to write the RTF so that you don't have to manipulate the RTF by hand?